# uv smart projecting multiple objects via python loop issue

Tags: python

i have 100 of objects in a scene, which i need to assign UV (smart project), so they don't rely in default cubical space of shader. i tried following code ( written in few minutes) upon running, it only work (as expected)on first or last object. just can't figure out why. only one object shows texture after running. ahh..

```
import bpy

meshObjs = []
for each in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if each.type == 'MESH':
        meshObjs.append (each)

    # clear selection
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    # iterating mesh objects
for obj in meshObjs:
    d = obj.data
    #obj.select = True
    bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
    obj.update_from_editmode()
    print (obj.name) 
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
    obj.update_from_editmode()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    obj.select = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the object as the active object. You can add `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects.active = obj` at the beginning of your loop.